# Is there any service or way to manage FTP/SFTP access giving to multiple users on AWS EC2 Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp

Is there any service or way to manage FTP/SFTP access giving to multiple users on AWS EC2 Instance?

I am working on a client's website where the client wants to add 1 more developer and asked me to give him access to the server. Also, he wants to remove that developer access once his work is finished. Is it possible to add an FTP/SFTP connection manager on EC2 Instance? or something similar?

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl where should I take it?

Answer (score 0):

AWS has a [fully-managed SFTP service for Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-transfer-for-sftp-fully-managed-sftp-service-for-amazon-s3/), but it appears that you are running FTP on an Amazon EC2 instance.

AWS does not have access to your instance. Therefore, *you* would be responsible for making any configuration changes on the instance that you need. You might want to do this via the [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html), which can execute commands on an EC2 instance if the AWS Systems Manager agent has been installed. However, *you* would be responsible for writing the script of commands that you want executed on the instance.

I will also mention that FTP is quite an old protocol and an old way of transferring data. If possible, you should consider using Amazon S3 for storage of files rather than an FTP server.

Comment: I am sorry for misleading, I was expecting answers both for SFTP and FTP. I have updated my question now. I did check the SFTP service link in AWS you provided but didn't get how to configure it. I just looked at it again, I now think that each developer needs to have their IAM User created in AWS and then we can provide them access. 

Any suggestion on the type of access we should give to the new developer in IAM user account?

Comment: The "AWS Transfer for SFTP" service is an option if you do not want to run your own SFTP server. If you _are_ running your own FTP/SFTP server, then you are responsible for configuring it.

Comment: I am not running SFTP server. Currently, I am using the default settings and using PEM file for SSH and FTP. My team is using the same, the issue is with the new developer from somewhere else recruited for a small period of time. I had to provide him the PEM file since there was no other way.